# Check if a property exists in a list of custom class

Tags: c#

I have a list of my custom class(which has properties like Name,Age,Address).How can i check whether I have a property called "Name" in my list of custom class. I dont want to check if an item exists for the property Name , rather i did like to check if the property exists or not.

Any help on this?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Are you saying that you have a `List<MyCustomClass>` and you want to make sure each item has a given property?  If that property is on `MyCustomClass` then it's a safe assumption that it's on every item in a strongly typed list of that class.  Or do you mean check if the property isn't null or empty?  Or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a class named `Foo` and you want to check if a property `Bar` exists you can do the following using reflection:

```
bool barExists = typeof(Foo).GetProperties()
                            .Where(x => x.Name == "Bar")
                            .Any();
```

or shorter even (thanks for the reminder @Adam Robinson):

```
bool barExists = typeof(Foo).GetProperties().Any(x => x.Name == "Bar")
```

Comment: Could I ask if there is any difference between blah.Where(predicate).Any() and blah.Any(predicate)? Always interested in how folks make use of linq.  Cheers.

Comment: @Dan: In concept, no, there is no difference. In implementation, using `Where(predicate)` will introduce more overhead (because it'll spin up a custom `WhereEnumerableIterator`) than just calling the `Any` overload. It's not likely to make an appreciable difference, but still, why add it if it's not needed?

Comment: Yep, the overload makes it much more succinct. I usually just start with a `Where` clause and go from there when I build up a solution - sometimes I then forget to compact/optimize once I have arrived at a solution. The short form is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(typeof(CustomClass).GetProperties().Where(i => i.Name == FieldYoureLookingFor).Count() > 0)
{
DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: While it's unlikely to make a real difference, using `Any(condition)` is preferable to `Where(condition).Count() > 0`

Comment: thank you so much for your reply it worked. How do I save the value in this field, i mean the correct syntax.

Comment: `PropertyInfo info = typeof(CustomClass).GetProperties().Where(i => i.Name == FieldYoureLookingFor);
object value = info.GetValue(yourObject, null);`

Comment: PropertyInfo info = typeof(CustomClass).GetProperties().Where(i => i.Name == FieldYoureLookingFor); Gives me an error cannot implicity convert bool to system.web.processinfo...Am I missing anything?

Comment: Can you show us what you use in your Where clause?  Also, you might want to check if the returned collection is Empty before assigning it to info.  I didn't to keep my comment short but it would go something like:
`IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> results = typeof(CustomClass).GetProperties().Where(i => i.Name == FieldYoureLookingFor);  if(results.Count > 0) { object value = results.Single().GetValue(yourObject, null); }`

Comment: Though I dont have any property with the name a it still displays results as not equal to null which is wrong..IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> results = typeof(LineItem).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name == "a");

Answer (score 1):

Here a goes an object extension method that tell you whether a given PropertyName exists in any given object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace StackOverflow.MyExtensions
{
    public static class ObjectExtentions
    {

        public static Boolean PropertyExists(this object Object, string PropertyName)
        {

            var ObjType = Object.GetType();

            var TypeProperties = ObjType.GetProperties();

            Boolean PropertyExists = TypeProperties
                    .Where(x => x.Name == PropertyName)
                    .Any();

            return PropertyExists;

        }

    }
}
```

Here goes a usage sample:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using StackOverflow.MyExtensions;

namespace StackOverflow
{


    class Person
    {
        string _FirstName; // FirstName

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _FirstName; }
            set { _FirstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName;

    }


    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person SamplePerson = new Person();

            if (SamplePerson.PropertyExists("FirstName"))
                Console.WriteLine("Yes! Property does exist!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Nope, property does not exist on object SamplePerson");

            if (SamplePerson.PropertyExists("LastName"))
                Console.WriteLine("Yes! Property does exist!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Nope, property does not exist on object SamplePerson");

        }
    }

}
```

Cheers